# There was a problem automatically reconnecting the client to Node.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

**I am working on reconnecting the client automatically within the site
Everything works fine
But when adding a timer reconnct = setInterval(()
It becomes when the connection is re-established
Reconnects all clients
Not with the wanted person
What should I do?
Is there a way to avoid disconnecting everyone when reconnecting?
Here are the codes**

```
                                  io.on("connection", function (socket) {
                                    if (socket.recovered) {
                                    if(UserInfo[socket.id]){
                                     clearInterval(reconnct);
                                    }
                                    const isoffonline = OnlineUser.findIndex((v) => v.id == socket.id);
                                    if (isoffonline != -1) {
                                    OnlineUser[isoffonline].stat = 5;
                                      socket.join(UserInfo[socket.id]['idroom']);
                                         io.emit("SEND_EVENT_EMIT_SERVER", { cmd: "USERS_UR", data: [socket.id, UserInfo[socket.id]['idroom']] });
                                      io.emit("SEND_EVENT_EMIT_SERVER", { cmd: "u^", data: OnlineUser[isoffonline] });
                                    }
                                } else {
                                }
                                  socket.emit("SEND_EVENT_EMIT_SERVER", {
                                    cmd: "pw",
                                    data: ShowPowers
                                  });
                                      


                            
socket.on("disconnect", function (v) {
  if (UserInfo[socket.id]) {
if(SiteSetting.reconnect && UserInfo[socket.id]['islogin'] == "عضو"){
if(ListEnter.length > 0){
ListEnter.splice(ListEnter.findIndex((v) => v.id == socket.id),1);
};
const isoffonline = OnlineUser.findIndex((v) => v.id == socket.id);
if (isoffonline != -1) {
OnlineUser[isoffonline]['stat'] = 5;
OnlineUser[isoffonline]['idroom'] =  null;
socket.leave(UserInfo[socket.id]['idroom']);
io.emit("SEND_EVENT_EMIT_SERVER", { cmd: "u^", data: OnlineUser[isoffonline] });
io.emit("SEND_EVENT_EMIT_SERVER", { cmd: "USERS_UR", data: [socket.id, null] });
}
reconnct = setInterval(()=>{
  socket.emit("SEND_EVENT_EMIT_SERVER", {
    cmd: "ev",
    data: "window.onbeforeunload = null; location.href=\"/\";"
  });
  UserDisconnect({
  id: socket.id,
  state: 1
});
},150000);

}else{
  if (UserInfo[socket.id]) {
    socket.emit("SEND_EVENT_EMIT_SERVER", {
      cmd: "ev",
      data: "window.onbeforeunload = null; location.href=\"/\";"
    });
    UserDisconnect({
      id: socket.id,
      state: 1
    });
  };
};
}
});
```

I want to fix setInterval()) in Node.js

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to emit the event to the wanted person only, you can try using something as the below with `socket.to` and target a specific user

```
const clientId = 'user123';
socket.to(clientId).emit('message', 'Hello, specific client!');
```